# Can some one explain what happening in memory for this statement in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have the following C code and I'm trying to understand it.

```
char buffer[128];
A* a = (A*) &buffer[sizeof(A*)];
```

At first, I was trying to do this with `A* a = (A*) buffer[sizeof(A*)];`
this gives me a warning and I guess it is because this would actually give me the char at `sizeof(A*)` and cast it?. Another confusion is since buffer is already a pointer to the first element of the array why do I need a `&`operator to get a pointer to cast to `A*`. Can some one help me to understand this piece of code?

Thanks!

Comment: You mention a warning. What was it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line in question takes your 128-byte `buffer`, looks at the index at `sizeof(A*)` and returns a reference to it, casting it to a pointer of type `A`.

> Another confusion is since buffer is already a pointer to the first element of the array why do I need a &operator to get a pointer to cast to A*.

Well, this is because, when you write index the `buffer` array by using a subscript with`[]`, it returns the value pointed to at that index of the buffer, not the memory location itself. By prepending `&` you are getting the memory address of that data.

Answer (score 1):

`(A*)` - Cast to pointer of data structure A

`&buffer[]` - Go to the location in memory pointed to by buffer

`[sizeof(A*)]` - Use the size of a pointer to an A data structure as the index